# Datagrid row delete issue during edit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, datagrid

I have a data grid and I'm trying to delete the entire row, its working fine only if I select the entire row. But is is not working if I select single cell (cursor focus on single cell in edit mode) and delete it.

Below is my code:

```
private void DeleteData_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (grdData == null || grdData.SelectedIndex < 0) return;

    grdData.RemoveRow(grdData.SelectedIndex);
}
```

What is the issue and/or how can I resolve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete underlying data source row and rebind the data.

If you are using a datatable as datasource, you can do something like this:

```
private void DeleteData_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (grdData == null || grdData.SelectedIndex < 0) return;

    DataTable sourceData = (DataTable)grdData.DataSource;    
    sourceData.Rows[ grdData.SelectedIndex].Delete();    
    grdData.DataSource = sourceData;
    grdData.DataBind();
}
```